# Simulated two keyevents with adb shell for ALT, SHIFT, etc

Tags: android, adb

With `adb shell input keyevent` certain key events can be simulated. There are also modifier keys like `SHIFT_LEFT`, `ALT_RIGHT` etc.

I would like to simulate two keys, for instance SHIFT + A, but

```
 adb shell input keyevent SHIFT_LEFT; keyevent A
```

results only in a simple `a` on the screen.

Comment: for maj, you can input text "A"

Comment: @njzk2 I know, it was only an example. The symbols I am really after are considered Unicode characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if Shift + A is needed then you will have to do following sequence

```
Press shift
Press A
Release A
Release shift
```

this can be done by using

command format: sendevent device type code value

```
[command]     [device]             [type]    [code]   [value]
sendevent    /dev/input/event0    1          229      1
```

/dev/input/event0 is the device to send it to

[type] 1 is unknow for me ( maybe code for physical button on device )

[code] 229 is the MENU button of the emulator

[value] 1 is keydown or press down ( for keyup or up use 0 )

i wrote a batch file for sending the event to the device like below:

```
adb -s emulator-5554 shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 229 1
adb -s emulator-5554 shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 229 0
```

[Ref](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/android-beginners/il2PqSKRFNI/jzG1Uk9gbs4J)

Comment: I have **[this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mahendranv/0958a2cbda303191c507/raw/22c6443d1cb1d1ebd03656e3ee9b030b10d82cb7/CTRL+N)** snippet for Ctrl+N not working. Any Idea ?

Comment: what are you planing to do with Ctrl* also do you get the ctrl on your android device. If so you might want to write the program and get the actual keycode on android device.

Comment: In my application I am using set of shortcuts Ctrl+N, Ctrl+C also verified the keycode is correct.