# Send CTRL + T over ADB using sendevent or input keyevent

Tags: android, adb, chromium

## What I'm trying to do

I am trying to open a tab in Chromium using ADB. What I'm trying to accomplish is opening a tab within chromium using their hotkeys. I'm trying to hit this line of code from their source: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/KeyboardShortcuts.java?rcl=120f241e3761e263d28f1b9194bd6cbf7aa56efd&l=215

## Here's the various things I've tried:

Using Android Key Events: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 114 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 48 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 114 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 48 0
```

Using Android key codes from source:
https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git/+/android-msm-hammerhead-3.4-kk-r1/include/linux/input.h

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 97 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 20 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 97 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 20 0
```

Using keyevent inputs

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_CTRL_RIGHT
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_T
```

## An alternative way (but not what I'm trying to accomplish)

One way I've managed to accomplish opening a tab, but not a way I'm in favor of us using intents. I want to open the tab using the actual key events instead of using this intent.

Way that does open a tab:

```
adb shell am start -a "android.intent.action.VIEW" -d "google.com"
```

## Other StackOverflow articles I've referenced:

- [Simulated two keyevents with adb shell for ALT, SHIFT, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260062/simulated-two-keyevents-with-adb-shell-for-alt-shift-etc/14260449)
- [Simulating combination of key presses from ADB terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204766/simulating-combination-of-key-presses-from-adb-terminal)

Comment: 1. Are you sure that the right event file for your devce is event0? 2. In your first attempt (key codes 114 and 48) I think you should swap the last two lines - release the 'T' before you release the 'ctrl' key. 3. In your second attempt - you press the 'T' first, and only then the 'ctrl' - fix it.

Comment: Tried swapping the last two lines of the first attempt. No change :\

I don't understand what you're suggesting with the second attempt. 97 is the keycode for CTRL and 20 is the keycode for T. 

Also, how do I figure out which event input is correct?

Comment: @ryandawkins this is late but `adb shell getevent` will show the list of inputs and their names, that can help decide which one to send to

Comment: Unable to edit that comment, for the android emulator, I needed to do `adb shell` and then `getevent` in the prompt, didnt print anything when I ran it directly

Answer (score 0):

You have to send `0 0 0` after every event:

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 29 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 20 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 29 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 20 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0
```

(This uses LEFT_CTRL (`29`) instead of RIGHT_CTRL (`97`). Just swap out the numbers if you want to use RIGHT_CTRL. For any other key, check [Linux's keyboard input keycodes](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm.git/+/android-msm-hammerhead-3.4-kk-r1/include/linux/input.h).)

Here's some convenience functions to use in `adb shell`:

```bash
keydown() { sendevent /dev/input/eventN 1 "$1" 1; sendevent /dev/input/eventN 0 0 0; }
keyup() { sendevent /dev/input/eventN 1 "$1" 0; sendevent /dev/input/eventN 0 0 0; }
```

Replace `eventN` with the actual event file, which you can find by running `getevent` without any args and inspecting the list.

##### Explanation

The Linux input event queue requires [the special `EV_SYN` event](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt) to be sent after bunches of events to process the events. (Quick summary: `EV_SYN`, the "synchronize" event, seperates temporally distinct sets of events.) This corresponds to event `0 0 0`. You can see this if you run `getevent` and try performing the event manually:

```
emu64xa:/ # getevent -l /dev/input/event0
EV_KEY       KEY_S                DOWN
EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
EV_KEY       KEY_S                UP
EV_SYN       SYN_REPORT           00000000
```

And `getevent` without the `-l` flag displays the numbers you need to use:

```
emu64xa:/ # getevent /dev/input/event0
0001 001f 00000001
0000 0000 00000000
0001 001f 00000000
0000 0000 00000000
```